# Error while Install 32feet (MS Help 2.x runtime)

Tags: c#, bluetooth, windows-7-x64, 32feet

When I try to install 32feet i got this error:

[link to photo](http://oi59.tinypic.com/elchgy.jpg)

> H2Reg.exe
>
> ** Error **
>
> MS Help 2.x runtime files are not installed on this PC.
>
> Installation/registeration of Help files cannot proceed.